# Flex: Replacing characters in a string based on a mask

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, string-formatting, masking

I am attempting to apply a mask to another string to replace all wildcards in one string with the matching characters in the matching index while keeping the non-wildcard characters.

Eg:

```
starting string:         "1234-234-3456-45-9876"  
mask string:             "____-___-0001-__-____" 
when applied together:   "1234-234-0001-45-9876"
```

Is this some usage of Regex I haven't seen before?  I tried to understand the string.replace() type methods, but I don't think these apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
private function checkString():void
{

var starting:String = "1234-234-3456-45-9876"; 
var mask:String = "____-___-0001-__-____";

for(var i:int=0;i<starting.length;i++)
{
  if(mask.charAt(i).match("[0-9]"))
    {
      starting = starting.substr(0,i) + mask.charAt(i) +  starting.substr(i+1);
    }
}
    Alert.show(starting);
}
```

It will mask your string. Check result of alert.

Comment: That helps alot. I know very well how to do this multiple ways in C# but I was stumped on this in Flex.